# React Native Router Flux: drawer takes up entire page

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I want to implement a drawer with React Native Router Flux.

This is my current configuration in app.js:

```
            <Router>
              <Stack key="root">
                <Scene key="fullApp"  component={fullApp} hideNavBar={true} />
                <Scene key="comments" component={Comment} hideNavBar={true} />
                <Scene key="createComment" component={CreateComment} hideNavBar={true} />
                <Scene key="playerPage"  component={PlayerPage} hideNavBar={true}/>
                <Scene key="saveFilter" animationEnabled={false} component={SaveFilter} hideNavBar={true}/>
                <Scene key="leagueSelect" gesturesEnabled={false} component={LeagueSelect} hideNavBar={true}/>
                <Scene key="filter" component={Filter} hideNavBar={true}/>
                <Drawer
                  hideNavBar
                  key="mainDrawer"
                  contentComponent={MainDrawer}
                  drawerWidth={250}
                  drawerPosition="right"
                  drawerIcon={drawerIcon}
                >
                  <Scene key="slide"  component={MainDrawer} hideNavBar={true}/>
                </Drawer>
              </Stack>
            </Router>
```

When I call `Actions.mainDrawer()` in another component, the Drawer opens, but it takes up the entire page; it's like it's opening a scene, not a drawer.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `Actions.drawerOpen()` to open your drawer